# print this with $ as shown using python formatting

Tags: python, formatting

I need to add $ to the price section as shown here  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLNKJ.png)

How to do this using f-string

```
for name, shares, price, change in report:

print(f'{name:>10s} {shares:>10d}  {price:>10.2f} {change:>10.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
report = [
    ['AA', 100, 9.22, -22.98],
    ['IBM', 50, 106.28, 15.18]
]

for name, shares, price, change in report:
    price = f'${price:.2f}'
    print(f'{name:>10} {shares:>10d}  {price:>10} {change:>10.2f}')
```

Prints:

```
    AA        100       $9.22     -22.98
   IBM         50     $106.28      15.18
```